# addressing a child from another class created by getdefinitionbyname

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a class "pagecompiler" which does the following:

```
if(page){
                removeChild(page);
            }
            switch (appModel.currentPage){
                case "Programma":
                case "Winkelwagen":
                case "Films":
                case "Contact":
                case "Reserveer":
                    var pageClass:* = getDefinitionByName("be.reynaertvincent.view.pages."+appModel.currentPage+"Page");
                    page = new pageClass();
                    addChild( page );
                    break;
}
```

so it creates a page depending on the switch, the names are (contactpage, filmspage, contactpage, etc.)

each of these pages extend from a class called "page".

And in "page" class I do the following:

```
contentBg = new ContentBg();
sidebarBg = new SidebarBg();
addChild(contentBg);
addChild(sidebarBg);
```

Now what I would like is to apply a tween on contentBg when I do the following in pagecompiler:

```
if(page){
   removeChild(page);
}
```

but I can't seem to address contentBg from there. I tried:

```
if(page.contentBg){
   tweenlite.to(page.contentBg,blablabla);
   //removeChild(page);
}
```

but it doesn't get recognized. Anyone having any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a number of problems with your code.  If you correct them, your problem should be solved:

1. You should stick to naming conventions: Class names should start with an upper case letter.  So it should be `Page` instead of `page`. Otherwise, you have a member variable with the same name as a type - and potential compilation errors.
2. `getDefinitionByName()` is a costly way of instantiating a class in terms of performance, and since it also isn't type safe, you are dealing with a potential problem.  Since you already know which classes you are going to instantiate, why not just make `page` an instance of `Page` and extend your switch statement:

   ```
   private var page:Page;


   // some code here


   switch (appModel.currentPage){
       case "Programma":
           page = new ProgrammaPage();
           break;
       case "Winkelwagen":
           page = new WinkelwagenPage();
           break;
       case "Films":
           page = new FilmsPage();
           break;
       case "Contact":
           page = new ContactPage();
           break;
       case "Reserveer":
           page = new ReserveerPage();
           break;
       }
   addChild( page );
   ```
3. If you make `page` an instance of `*`, as is implied above, you need to cast to the `Page` class in order to access its contentBg property.  Something like this:

   ```
   tweenlite.to (Page(page).contentBg, ....);
   ```

This last point, however, should already be solved if you follow the first two hints, since the compiler now knows that `page` is of type `Page`.  It is also a nice example why the lower case naming mentioned above doesn't work, as `page(page).contentBg` is obviously ambiguous.

Comment: Very good points altogether :) I wouldn't encourage having contentBg as a public variable though , it seems better to keep it protected and simply signal the Page class to deal with it when it is removed...

Comment: That depends on the rest of the Page class.  If it's just a convenient container for some DisplayObjects, and all the logic happens somewhere else, there is really no need to encapsulate.

Comment: Wow, when i see answers like this i know i have alot of things to learn.Tried this and works perfectly. Didnt know you could compile things like this. Just mentioning that all classes are named with upper class thou. Just not used to typing it outside of flash builder. Should have added it in the sample code.

Answer (score 0):

In your page class , you could create a public method:

```
  public function removeFromStage():void
  { 
       TweenLite.to ( contentBg , etc...   {.....  onComplete: remove})
  }

  //Called when the Tween is complete
  private function remove():void
  {
      parent.removeChild( this );

      //may come handy , don't forget to add a listener if you do this :)
      dispatchEvent ( new Event ( Event.COMPLETE ) );
  }
```

Then you can call it like this

```
if(page != null ){
   //add Complete event listener if necessary...
   page.removeFromStage();
 }
```

Comment: Shame i can only accept 1 answer as this was a nice solution as well. Will be usefull later on thou, tyvm